# bufio.Scanner: how to know if we are processing a new line or a truncated string?

Tags: go, buffer

I basically need to process each string line from a limited buffer that is read from a stream. Using the bufio.Scanner I can go line-by-line with the scanner but had to use what seems to be an over-complicated solution to detect *"truncation"*. Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks a lot. I'm not tight to any lib or anything.

```
func (p *Parser) Read(data []byte, tmpline *string, n int, bufSize int) {
    var line string
    strdata := string(data)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(strings.NewReader(strdata))
    line = ""
    for scanner.Scan() {
        if line != "" {
            if p.lineProcessor != nil {
                p.lineProcessor(line)
            }
        }
        line = scanner.Text()
        if *tmpline != "" {
            line = *tmpline + line //prepend line here
            *tmpline = ""
        }
    }
    if n == bufSize && data[bufSize-1] != '\n' { //detecting a fragment here, overcomplicated?
        *tmpline = line
    } else {
            //fmt.Println("last line >[" + line + "]")
            if p.lineProcessor != nil {
                p.lineProcessor(line)
            }
    }
}

func (p *Parser) Handle(r io.Reader, bufSize int) ([]byte, error) {
    var out []byte
    buf := make([]byte, bufSize)
    var n int
    var err error
    tmpline := ""
    for {
        n, err = r.Read(buf[:])
        if n > 0 {
            data := buf[:n]
            p.Read(data, &tmpline, n, bufSize)
        }
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                err = nil
            }
            break
        }
    }
    return out, err
}

main
...
cmd := exec.Command("ping", "8.8.8.8")

//var stdout, stderr []byte
var errStdout, errStderr error
//this is the type of stream I want to process **stdoutIn** and **stderrIn**
stdoutIn, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
stderrIn, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()
// 10 is the bufSize
parser.Init(stdoutIn, stderrIn, wg, 10, lineProcessor)
...
```

**EDIT**: I tried to implement the proposed solution. Now I have broke what was working (even though seemed overcomplicated). The output seems to be very funky. Here's the FULL CODE and FULL OUTPUT:

```
package main
import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "sync"
)
type LineProcessor func(string)
type Parser struct {
    r             io.Reader
    lineProcessor LineProcessor
    scanner       bufio.Scanner
}

func (p *Parser) Init(stdoutIn io.Reader, stderrIn io.Reader,
    wg sync.WaitGroup,
    lineProcessor LineProcessor) {
    wg.Add(2)
    p.lineProcessor = lineProcessor
    p.scanner = *bufio.NewScanner(stdoutIn)
    go p.Handler(stdoutIn, wg)
    go p.Handler(stderrIn, wg)
}
func (p *Parser) Handler(r io.Reader, wg sync.WaitGroup) { // ([]byte, error)
    var line string
    for p.scanner.Scan() {
        line = p.scanner.Text()
        if p.lineProcessor != nil {
            p.lineProcessor(line)
        }
    }
    wg.Done()
}
func lineProcessor(line string) {
    fmt.Println(line)
}
func main() {
    var err error
    cmd := exec.Command("ping", "8.8.8.8") 

    var errStdout, errStderr error
    stdoutIn, _ := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    stderrIn, _ := cmd.StderrPipe()

    var parser Parser

    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    parser.Init(stdoutIn, stderrIn, wg, lineProcessor)

    err = cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Start() failed with '%s'\n", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Waiting\n")
    wg.Wait()

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("cmd.Run() failed with %s\n", err)
    }
    if errStdout != nil || errStderr != nil {
        log.Fatal("failed to capture stdout or stderr\n")
    }
}

$./buggysolution
Waiting
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=52 time=4.786 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=3.661 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=4.117 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=4.172 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=8 ttl=52 time=3.584 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=10 ttl=52 time=4.301 ms
mp_seq=11 ttl=52 time=4.534 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=12 ttl=52 time=4.349 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=13 ttl=52 time=4.923 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=14 ttl=52 time=4.349 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=15 ttl=52 time=4.106 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=16 ttl=52 time=4.270 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=17 ttl=52 time=4.231 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=18 ttl=52 time=4.915 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=19 ttl=52 time=4.487 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=20 ttl=52 time=4.182 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=21 ttl=52 time=4.369 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=22 ttl=52 time=4.287 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=23 ttl=52 time=3.922 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=24 ttl=52 time=4.905 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=25 ttl=52 time=4.226 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=27 ttl=52 time=4.052 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=29 ttl=52 time=3.453 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=31 ttl=52 time=5.103 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=33 ttl=52 time=4.066 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=35 ttl=52 time=4.128 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=37 ttl=52 time=4.982 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=4.206 ms
.64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=39 ttl=52 time=4.215 ms
.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=4.218 ms
tl=52 time=3.650 ms
8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=3.661 ms
ttl=52 time=4.791 ms
: icmp_seq=5 ttl=52 time=3.581 ms
 ttl=52 time=4.211 ms
 icmp_seq=4 ttl=52 time=4.117 ms
4 ttl=52 time=4.245 ms
icmp_seq=7 ttl=52 time=4.955 ms
45 ttl=52 time=4.518 ms
cmp_seq=6 ttl=52 time=4.172 ms
=46 ttl=52 time=4.764 ms
seq 9
^C
```

Thanks for any fix.

Comment: When is a line "truncated" ? Could you add some example input lines ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "truncation"?

Comment: truncated input would be, for example, if the buffer you are reading is for example 712 bytes in 4 lines, but your buffer is only 512 and p.Read will only get 512 bytes and only 3 lines and 34bytes of the last line, so you need to store the remaining and prepend the first line of the next buffer that will come with 200 bytes.

Comment: You're first chunking the stream, and then trying to read lines from it. that's overkill, and likely to be wrong. Instead, use the scanner directly to read from the reader.

Comment: @bserdar could you please provide an example for that? The input for this code (data byte array) comes from processing the output of exec.Command execution that runs "forever", it's not a network data or a flat file.

Comment: @martin your code doesn't make sense if your intent is to process unbounded input stream. What does the function return? If the input is really unbounded, then you should: 1) Create the scanner using the reader directly, 2) Process the lines as they come. You should either process each line once you read them, pass the lines to a callback function for processing, or read the input in a separate goroutine and send the lines via a channel. The reader function will not return until all lines are read, so you either read and keep everything or process each line as you read them.

Comment: it doesn't matter what the function returns, you can replace the printf for a callback like I did in the edit, the point is to be able to processes the input for a daemon that keeps throwing output in the pipe from exec.Command,

Comment: btw, the code is working perfectly, I just need a better way of doing this, see if you have enough information now @bserdar

Comment: In that case, the answer by @mh-cbon is the best way to do this: use scanner directly.

Comment: @bserder I tried that, see the edit, the full code and output are there. Now it gives me a funky output. Thank you for looking into this.

Comment: I started two consumers over the same producer, the other one was supposed to be for stderr, sorry guys and thanks a lot for all the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not how a `bufio.Scanner` should be used.

The `bufio.Scanner` takes a reader and can return lines directly out of it.

`bufio.Scanner` will fail if the token is larger than `bufio.Scanner.maxTokenSize` which by default is `MaxScanTokenSize` but it won't return truncated results.

You can also check the test suite at https://golang.org/src/bufio/scan_test.go#L214 (not that the MaxTokenSize method being used is defined with a special scheme to exists only during tests see https://golang.org/src/bufio/export_test.go#L16)

You can also define your own underlying buffer before scanning to change that value https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner.Buffer

to roll your own version it might look like this https://play.golang.org/p/kDcO6eZPVhY however going down that path requires you write additional tests and benchmarks.

---

After multiple comments, here what OP was looking for:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {

    cmd := exec.Command("ping", "8.8.8.8")
    var out io.Reader
    {
        stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        stderr, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        out = io.MultiReader(stdout, stderr)
    }
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    // defer cmd.Process.Kill()
    s := bufio.NewScanner(out)
    for s.Scan() {
        log.Println(s.Text())
    }
    // if out closes, cmd closed.
    log.Println("all done")
}
```

Comment: thanks for the effort @mh-cbon, if I not supposed to use Scanner, what would be the alternative? I edited and added more info, see if this is clear now

Comment: using a bufio.Scanner is correct. But re instantiate a new Scanner to scan one line is not a correct usage. Assuming ping outputs to stdout, you can make a `bufio.NewScanner(cmd.Stdout)` and handles lines spitted out by the scanner directly.

Comment: please take a look at the edit I made, see if that's what you mean and see if you can find what's wrong. thx!!